# How to get Order No. at event sales_order_place_after using event-observer model?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, events

How to get Order No. at event sales_order_place_after using event-observer model?

I want to get Order No. as soon as order is placed by customer.

I want to pass that order no. to another external php file & include that php file in the Observer.php? How Can I do that?

I am trying to include external php file in Magento but I am unable to do that.

Observer.php:

```
<?php

 include("connection/Final/Function1.php");     
class Sample_Event_Model_Observer {

    public function Mytestmethod($observer) {

        $event = $observer->getEvent();  //Fetches the current event
        $eventmsg = "Current Event Triggered : <I>" . $event->getName() . "</I>";
        echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($eventmsg);

    $Id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();   
    $incrementid = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();

    $ordermsg1 = "Current order Id : <I>" . $Id . "</I>";
        echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($ordermsg1);
    $ordermsg2 = "Current increment Id : <I>" . $incrementid . "</I>";
        echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($ordermsg2);

    $p = new testDatabase(); 
        $p -> setId($incrementid);
        $p -> dbConnect();
      }
}
?>
```

Function1.php:

```
<?php 
class testDatabase 
{ 
    public function setId($getId)
    {
        $incrementid=$getId;
        echo $incrementid;
    }

    public function dbConnect()
     {  
            $db_name = "magento";
                $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "magento", "password");

        If (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
            $seldb = mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);
        If ($seldb) 
        {
            echo "Database Found ";
            $query = "INSERT INTO sample(id) VALUES($incrementid)" ;
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            print "id is added to the database"; 
            mysql_close($seldb);
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Database NOT Found ";
        } 
     }
}
```

How can I access variable `$incrementid` in `Function1.php`?  My problem is I am unable to access `$incrementid` as it is unable to insert in my sample table.

I have caught s`ales_order_place_after` event. So that once customer press PLACE ORDER, I can include Function1.php & it will take increment/order id & I can able to access Functions in it that will do needful job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get this from event

```
$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId() 

$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId()
```

what's the point of including external files :) you can load any model by

`Mage::getModel('your/extension_model')`

or if you are doing spaghetti like your question indicates then use `require('path/to/file')` and remember that this is a big nono.

Comment: Hi Aton, I have external PHP file sample.php conating class mysql with function of connection for mysql, fetching data, insertion of data into mysql custom table & another class oracle with function of connection for Oracle & insertion in oracle. So how can I include this file in Observer.php or how can I call/execute this file as soon as customer press place order tab? So what i am thinking is passing the generated order id to that file & execute that query by including/calling that file?  Plz guide me...

Comment: Hi Aton, I agree that there are methods for MySQL connection. but what about Oracle datatbase as we don't have adapter/support for Oracle in Magento EE 1.10. So to insert data in Oracle I am using php file that connect to magento database, fetches data & insert it into oracle database. What can I do in such scenario as I need to do this whole process at the time of Order placement....thts why I am planning to include/call that external PHP file...guide me if i am wrong..

Comment: 1.11 has Oracle helpers, but not 1.10, so you are stuck with an external script until you upgrade.

Comment: HI Ben, we can't upgrade to 1.11 due to organization's constraint...Can u give any other suggestion in such case...

Comment: Well it is php after all and you can include anything and execute it in your observer method

Comment: HI Anton, I added my files. Plz take a look on that & tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why you need separate class for mysql connection after all ?

Comment: I have connected to Magento database through PHP & I want to fetch some data from Magento tables thts why created separate connection to Mysql & that class includes all my query functions.

Comment: HI Anton, I can use built-in methods for Mysql but what about Oracle? Thats why using external conection...

Comment: i can see that you are using mysql in your class or whatever you are after